# Longest common prefix in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, prefix

I am attempting to match files based on their longest common prefix, cpfx, and am a bit new to haskell. I am trying to take a list of lists and simply return the prefix they all share. For example:

```
cpfx ["obscure","obscures","obscured","obscuring"] --> "obscur"

cpfx ["abc", "ab", "abcd"] --> "ab"
```

I am trying to this with a couple helper methods, like so:

```
cpfx :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
cpfx [] = [] -- nothing, duh
cpfx (x:[]) = x -- only one thing to test, return it
cpfx (x:t) = cpfx' (x:t) 0 -- otherwise, need to test

cpfx' (x:[]) _ = []
cpfx' (x:t) n
-- call ifMatch to see if every  list matches at that location, then check the next one
      | ifMatch (x:t) n = x!!n + cpfx' x (n+1)
      | otherwise = []

-- ifMatch means if all words match at that location in the list
ifMatch (x:[]) _ = True
ifMatch (x:xs:[]) n = x!!n == xs!!n
ifMatch (x:xs:t) n
      | x!!n == x!!n = ifMatch xs n
      | otherwise = False
```

But I am getting the error: 
`Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]`

which I'm guessing is pertaining to the `ifMatch (x:t) n = x!!n + cpfx' x (n+1)` line.

Anything can I do to remedy this case?

Comment: Off-topic: `cpfx [] = [] -- nothing, duh` is not quite so "duh". The common prefix of an empty `[[a]]` is undefined, i.e. the common prefix could be *anything*, because there is nothing for it to be tested as a prefix of.

Answer (score 7):

## How to solve those errors

Note: While I will show you how to understand and solve those errors, I also present a more elegant version (at least from my point of view) below.

Whenever you end up with an infinite type, it is a good idea too add type signatures:

```
cpfx'   :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Char]
ifMatch :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Bool
```

Suddenly, we gain additional errors, two in

```
  | ifMatch (x:t) n = x!!n + cpfx' x (n+1)
```

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
    Expected type: [[Char]]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `x !! n'
```

```
    No instance for (Num [Char])
      arising from a use of `+'
```

and one in `ifMatch`:

```
  | x!!n == x!!n = ifMatch xs n
```

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
    Expected type: [[Char]]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the first argument of `ifMatch', namely `xs'
    In the expression: ifMatch xs n
```

Now, the error in `cpfx'` is quite simple: `x` is a `[Char]`, `x !! n` is a `Char`, and want to cons it onto a list, so use `:` instead of `+`. Also, you want to apply `cpfx'` to `t`, not to `x`. This also fixes your second error. In `ifMatch`, `x!!n == x!!n` is redundant, and `xs` has type `[Char]` and thus hasn't the right type for `ifMatch`. This is also a typo:

```
  | x!!n == xs!!n = ifMatch t n
```

However, now that we fixed those compilation errors, does your program actually make sense? In particular, what do you expect this lines to do:

```
ifMatch (x:xs) n = x!!n : cpfx' xs (n+1)
```

`(x:xs)` is the list of your words. However, you remove a word from your in every iteration, which is clearly not what you've meant. You want

```
ifMatch (x:xs) n = x!!n : cpfx' (x:xs) (n+1)
```

Overall we get the following code:

```
cpfx :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
cpfx []     = []
cpfx [x]    = x
cpfx (x:xs) = cpfx' (x:xs) 0
 
cpfx' :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Char]
cpfx' [x]    _ = []
cpfx' (x:xs) n
  | ifMatch (x:xs) n = x!!n : cpfx' (x:xs) (n+1)
  | otherwise = []

ifMatch :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Bool
ifMatch [x]      _ = True
ifMatch [x,y]    n = x!!n == y!!n
ifMatch (x:y:xs) n
      | x!!n == y!!n = ifMatch xs n
      | otherwise = False
```

## A simpler way using fold

Lets make our function a little bit simpler, but also more general by writing a `commonPrefix` for any type, that implements `==`:

```
commonPrefix :: (Eq e) => [e] -> [e] -> [e]
commonPrefix _ [] = []
commonPrefix [] _ = []
commonPrefix (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y    = x : commonPrefix xs ys
  | otherwise = []
```

If you're not used to that notation, think of `e` being `Char` for a while. Now, the common prefix of some words can be written as:

```
"hello" `commonPrefix` "hell" `commonPrefix` "hero"
```

Now the thing is, if you want to do something for a range of things, you usually use a [fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

> ```
> foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
> ```
>
> foldl, applied to a binary operator, a starting value (typically the left-identity of the operator), and a list, reduces the list using the binary operator, from left to right:
>
> ```
> foldl f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == (...((z `f` x1) `f` x2) `f`...) `f` xn
> ```

The last example looks exactly like our `` `commonPrefix` `` line before! However, we do not have a starting value, so we would use the first element of our list instead. Luckily, there's already [`foldl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl1), which does exactly that. Therefore, our previously complicated function boils down to:

```
commonPrefixAll :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
commonPrefixAll = foldl1 commonPrefix
```

The thing you should remember from this is: whenever you want to walk over multiple elements in a list in order to provide a single value, think about whether it's really necessary too look at all elements in every iteration. Usually, it's enough to concern only two elements at a time and then use the correct fold. See the section [Computing one answer over a collection in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#id592937) for more examples and information.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using explicit recursion quite easily:

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)
commonPrefix = map fromJust . takeWhile isJust . map the . transpose'
```

`the` takes a list, and returns `Nothing` if the elements of the list differ, otherwise it returns the unique element:

```
the :: Eq a => [a] -> Maybe a
the [] = Nothing
the (x:xs) 
  | and $ map (==x) xs = Just x
  | otherwise          = Nothing
```

`transpose'` is like `Data.List.transpose` but it truncates the result to the length of the shortest list:

```
transpose' xs = maybe [] id $ do
  ys <- mapM ht xs
  return $ (map fst ys) : (transpose' (map snd ys))
    where 
      ht [] = Nothing
      ht (x:xs) = Just (x,xs)
```

`transpose ["abc", "ab", "abcd"] == ["aaa","bbb","cc","d"]` but `transpose' ["abc", "ab", "abcd"] == ["aaa","bbb"]`

Answer (score 0):

The line you mentioned is indeed a problem.

Notice that the argument to `cpfx'` is `(x:[])`, i.e. a list of things all of which have the same type as `x`, but your recursive call just uses `x`. Thus you get the infinite type error: you are trying to identify the type of `x` with the type of `[x]`. (For concreteness, assume `x` is a `String`. Then you are suggesting that `x` has the type `String` (due to the pattern match of the argument) and `[String]` (by how `x` is used in the recursive call).

I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do, but you also have a problem in the same line because of `x!!n + ...`. Here, `x!!n` is (probably) a `Char`, but you are using the `+` operator, which is not defined for `Char`. You might mean `++` for list append, except `x!!n` is *not* a list, it is a single element. Thus you probably mean

```
[x!!n] ++ cpfx' ...
```

or

```
(x!!n) : cpfx' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to think about the problem:

Suppose you have a function for the longest common prefix:

```
lcp :: String -> String -> String
```

You can extend this to lists like this:

```
cpfx [a]       = a
cpfx [a,b]     = lcp a b
cpfx [a,b,c]   = lcp (lcp a b) c
cpfx [a,b,c,d] = lcp (lcp (lcp a b) c) d
...
```

This general recursion pattern is called a fold.

Answer (score 0):

What about an easy function like:

```
import Data.List

cpfx xs = comp (reverse $ minimum xs) (map reverse xs)
 where comp ys xs
    | True == (all (==True) $ map (\x->isSuffixOf ys x) xs)
                  = reverse ys
    | ys  == []   = []
    | otherwise   = comp (tail ys) xs
```

...and it works fine:[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/xjwqFjtC)